# Error while generating refresh token in google console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-ads-api

Error while generating refresh token in google console

I am trying to generate the refresh token using desktop flow.i have successfully created client id and client secret. I am getting the consent prompt but when I allow next page it’s throwing error 127.0.0.1 site can’t be reached . I am following the documentation and using generate_refresh_token.py to generate the token .
As per the doc it should work for both desktop and web app

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs/python/oauth-web

Comment: Do you have an HTTP server implemented that listens for the redirect callback? Edit your question and how what you implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to use an incognito browser window to copy the authentication url. It should be authenticated with the user(gmail) that has access to the google ads account. Also, Instead of using your local ip try using localhost:port that might help.

Best!
Makanist